# How to treat a torn iguana toe nail?

Tags: health, reptiles, medicines

Today when I picked up my iguana I noticed that his nail is almost off his toe but still attached, and there's blood on it, and the toe might be broken because I noticed that he keeps his hands off the ground a lot, because of pain I'm guessing.

I don't know how I'm going to treat him. I can't got to a reptile vet because where I live its illegal to bring reptiles here so we don't have a reptile vet around. I have to treat it myself.

Also he sometimes bites his front legs, is it possible that he pulled it off by himself?

Can anyone please tell how I can treat it?

This is him below.
[image]

### Update

Good news is, his nail fell of in his own now, I didn't have to pull it off myself. But I still want to know how to treat this injury. Another thing I noticed when I returned him to his cage that he's always lifting his hand up and keeps it up and shakes it! Does shaking his hands or his front leg means that he's in pain or that his toe is broken or is normal?! I really not much of an expert i just had him for couple of weeks. And he's my first reptile.

Below is a picture of his toes.
[image]

Comment: how far away is the nearest reptile vet? That is a huge potential problem, especially for a larger reptile that lives a long time like an iguana

Comment: Hand waving is something beardies do as communication. Not sure about iguanas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a small small article about it [Here](http://www.anapsid.org/ripped.html)

I dont own a green iguana but i read many forums about this injury. General consensus on many of the forums i saw is that it is a common injury when their claw is stuck in/on something and they jerk suddenly (from surprise or something) You should be able to treat it by soaking it a little in Betadine solution with just enough to brown the water a little and then tip it with something like neosporin. Do this daily until the wound clears up and make sure the enclosure stays clean (usually 6-7 days is what many people said but it is variable). You may bandage it with loose gauze but it should ONLY be done until it stops bleeding. After that it should be left open.